# Browse an xml tree and get a specific value

Tags: xml, search, xpath

Having this xml document

```
<root>
<bookstore>
    <presc:book>
        <presc:id>1</presc:id>
        <presc:title>Harry Potter</presc:title>
        <presc:price>29.99</presc:price>
    </presc:book>
    <presc:book>
        <presc:id>2</presc:id>
        <presc:title>Learning XML</presc:title>
        <presc:price>39.95</presc:price>
    </presc:book>
    <presc:book>
        <presc:id>3</presc:id>
        <presc:title>Java for Life</presc:title>
        <presc:price>54.49</presc:price>
    </presc:book>
</bookstore>
</root>
```

I'd like the get  the value of 'presc:price' only where 'pres:id'=2.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Sounds like a not valid XML document. Try `xmllint --valid file.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to close your `<root>` node at the end of your document.
Then because the `presc:` namespace is not declared, you need to use the `local-name()` function, as follows :

```
//*[local-name() = 'price' and ../id=2]
```

Answer (score 0):

If this XML had its `presc` namespace declared and you declared the same namespaces in whatever XML API you're using, the node you're trying to access would be

```
/root/bookstore/presc:book[presc:id = 2]/presc:price
```

If the XML had its namespaces declared but you weren't sure how to declare them in the XML API you're using, you could locate the price by doing this:

```
//*[*[local-name() = 'id'] = 2]/*[local-name() = 'price']
```

As it stands, your XML is not presently usable.

Comment: Thank you JLRishe. It's all ok.